# wrap all elements between two elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got the following HTML

```
<div class="bar-something"><div class="fn-label"> SOMETHING</div> </div>
<div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap1</div></div>
<div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap2</div></div>
<div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap3</div></div>
<div class="bar-something-else"><div class="fn-label"> SOMETHING</div></div>
<div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap1</div></div>
<div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap2</div></div>
<div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap3</div></div>
<div class="bar-something-odd"><div class="fn-label"> SOMETHING</div></div>
```

I want to wrap all the `bar-appointment` elements with another `DIV` so the `DOM` would then look like:

```
<div class="bar-something"><div class="fn-label"> SOMETHING</div> </div>
<div class="test">
  <div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap1</div></div>
  <div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap2</div></div>
<div>
<div class="bar-something-else"><div class="fn-label"> SOMETHING</div></div>
<div class="test">
    <div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap1</div></div>
    <div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap2</div></div>
    <div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap3</div></div>
    <div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap4</div></div>
    <div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap5</div></div>
</div>
<div class="bar-something-odd"><div class="fn-label"> SOMETHING</div></div>
```

I've tried the following but all the inner tags get wrapped too and I don't want that.

```
$('.bar-appointment').each(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil("div[class!='bar-appointment']").andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="test"></div>')});
```

I also tried using just `wrap` and this only wraps each element individually, not as a group as I would like.

What's the best way of me doing this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you can find all the first `bar-appointment` element(of the set) by removing `bar-appointment` elements which is having previous sibling as `bar-appointment`. Then iterate over that and find all the sibling which are `bar-appointment` elements and wrap all of them

```js
$('.bar-appointment').not('.bar-appointment + .bar-appointment').each(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil(":not(.bar-appointment)").addBack().wrapAll('<div class="test"> </div>')
})
```

```css
.test {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar-something"><div class="fn-label"> SOMETHING</div> </div>
<div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap1</div></div>
<div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap2</div></div>
<div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap3</div></div>
<div class="bar-something-else"><div class="fn-label"> SOMETHING</div></div>
<div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap1</div></div>
<div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap2</div></div>
<div class="bar-appointment"><div class="fn-label"> Ap3</div></div>
<div class="bar-something-odd"><div class="fn-label"> SOMETHING</div></div>
```